# Extract Information out of html

Tags: python, html, css

how can I extract the information of the appended html and save in a text file the following:
Paragraph-ID \t TokenID \t TokenCoordinates \t TokenContent

So, for example, the first lines should look like this:

> T102633    1    109,18,110,18    IV
>
> T102634    1    527,29,139,16    Seit
>
> ...

I'd like to use python. At the moment, I have the following:

```
root = lxml.html.parse('html-file').getroot()
tables = root.cssselect('table.main')
tables = root.xpath('//table[@class="main" and not(ancestor::table[@class="main"])]')


for elem in root.xpath("//span[@class='finereader']"):
    text = (elem.text or "") + (elem.tail or "")
        if elem.getprevious() is not None: # If there's a previous node
            previous = elem.getprevious()
            previous.tail = (previous.tail or "") + text # append to its tail
        else:
            parent = elem.getparent() # Otherwise use the parent
            parent.text = (parent.text or "") + text # and append to its text
        elem.getparent().remove(elem)

    txt = []

    txt += ([lxml.etree.tostring(t, method="html", encoding="utf-8") for t in tables])

    text = "\n".join(el for el in txt)
    output.write(text.decode("utf-8"))
```

This gives me something like this:

> [:T102633-1
> coord="109,18,110,18":]IV[:/T102633-1:]

Now, it's clear that I could use the string-find-method to extract the information I want. But is there no more elegant solution? With ".attrib" or something like that?
Thanks for any help!

Here, one can find the html: http://tinyurl.com/qjvsp4n

Comment: root is a node. you should iterate through it's children and attributes. currently don't remember, but try if .children and .attributes are valid root's attributes (since I don't remember the actual attributes, can't answer xD).

Comment: There are about a million questions a day on SO about [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org), BeautifulSoup, and `lxml.html`, and you couldn't find your answer in any of them? Or a tutorial?

Comment: Actually, I seriously doubt there are million/day even about just python. But yes, he could seek for a tutorial.

Comment: Hm, for this particular problem, I really found nothing :(

Comment: Try looking for the attributes I told you. Try looking into de lxml API. It's not about "this particular problem": You have to use xml (actually html) iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This code using BeautifulSoup gives all the `span`s you are interested in:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_file = open('html_file')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'main'})
# The first two tr's dont seem to contain the info you need, 
# so get rid of them
rows = table.find_all('tr')[2:] 
for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all('td')[1]
    span_element = data.find_all('span')
    for ele in span_element:
        print ele.text
```

Once you have the data in the format `[:T102639-3 coord="186,15,224,18":]L.[:/T102639-3:]`, use the python regex module to get the content.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\[:(.*):\](.*)\[:\/(.*):\]')
data = "[:T102639-3 coord="186,15,224,18":]L.[:/T102639-3:]"
res = re.search(pattern, data)
# res.group(1).split()[0] then gives 'T102639-3'
# res.group(1).split()[1] gives coord="186,15,224,18"
# res.group(2) gives 'L.'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I have 2 questions left: With your code, I have some characters which are printed out after "[:...:] ... [:/...:]" which we can ignore. How can these be ignored? 
Ok, the first question isn's as important as I thought, but the second one: Do you extract now the desired information ( Paragraph-ID \t TokenID \t TokenCoordinates \t TokenContent ) by string-find-methods, or how would you extract the information? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: @MarkF6 Using regexes. Updated the answer to that effect.